# how to check whether the string taken through gui is a binary string in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, logic

I am working on a watermarking project that embeds binary values (i.e 1s and 0s) in the image, for which I have to take the input from the user, and check certain conditions such as
1) no empty string
2) no other character or special character
3) no number other than 0 and 1
is entered.

The following code just checks the first condition. Is there any default function in Matlab to check whether entered string is binary

```
int_state = get(handles.edit1,'String'); %edit1 is the Tag of edit box
if isempty(int_state)`
    fprintf('Error: Enter Text first\n');
else
    %computation code
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such standard function, but the check can be easily implemented.
Use this error condition:

```
isempty(int_state) || any(~ismember(int_state, '01'))
```

It returns false (no error) if the string is non-empty and composed of '0's and '1's only.

The function `ismember` returns a boolean array that indicates for every character in `int_state` whether it is contained in the second argument, `'01'`. The advantage is that this can be generalized to arbitrary sets of allowed characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 2nd and 3rd can be combined together as 1 condition: your input string can only be a combination of 0 and 1? If it is so, then a small trick with `findstr` can do that:

```
if length(findstr(input_str, '1')) + length(findstr(input_str, '0')) == length(input_str)
    condition_satisfied;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

tf = isnumeric(A) returns true if A is a numeric array and false otherwise.

A numeric array is any of the numeric types and any subclasses of those types.

isnumeric(A)
ans =
     1 (when A is numeric).